# How to check for vulnerabilities in web application

Tags: web-applications, security, ajax, vulnerabilities, sql-injection

I have developed a web application using zend framework, mysql, and other client side technologies like javascript, jquery ajax, kendo grid, and so on.

I have completed development and have done several rounds of testing to make sure the functional part is correct.

Now I would like to check for the vulnerabilities in my application - vulnerabilities such as

```
           * sql injection 
           * ajax vulnerabilities
           * others
```

which I don't know of. I would like to ask you guys how to check this and make the application secure.  What methods should I use to secure my application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options, but before you delve in to them I'd take a very good look at the [Open Web Application Security Project](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/). OWASP has some brilliant documents and guidelines.

Personally, I'd begin by **conducting a full and proper code review**. Rather than checking for traditional issues, take a strong look at Secure Coding practice. (Once again, OWASP has some guidelines for this)

Things such as sanitisation checking, use of `eval()` and so on. From here you should be able to gain some insight - if only from looking at your code from a different point of view.

You could also do some **static source code analysis** which may pick up some of the above issues; however these shouldn't be the only form of source code analysis you do. It is a very good complimentary approach for a full and proper code review however. OWASP maintains a list of such tools [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools).

Once you've gained some confidence in the source code, you can begin to have a little fun! This is where ***'black box'* techniques**, such as fuzzing come in to play.

I recommend using something like the [Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP)](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) - give your application a good browse, preferably locally if you're on a shared host - or have a server that has critical applications running/is maintained elsewhere.

*Try and use every bit of functionality in your site using this proxy*. What this proxy *can be used for*, is check that any client facing parameters can't be given malicious input that will cause a security risk. However, what this proxy *can actually do* is much more - and it's worth digging in to the docs and looking at some of the advanced features.

If this still returns nothing then security really becomes an ongoing task:

- Checking error logs for suspicious entries (third parties using fuzzers, scanners or otherwise doing "*peculiar*" things.
- Internal Server Errors - can be a sign that someone is trying something
- Server load logs, for DoS attacks and so on.
- **Keeping up to date with the security releases regarding any dependencies you're using**

Not to overplay OWASP, as I've referred to them numerously in this answer - but it truly is a great project, and something I think every web developer should look in to.

It's also worth pointing out that security should be a concern as soon as the project is conceived, and if you don't take secure coding in to account when you begin - you may have a nightmare when you're trying to retrospectively secure an application.

Good luck!